# Sparse containers and iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I have implemented a sparse container, a basic *look-up table* (LUT).
It's basically a hybrid between a `vector<T>` and a `map<size_t, T>`:

1. The container is fixed-size (i.e. the size is specified as a constructor parameter and doesn't change)
2. Every slot is initially logically some default value (often just zero)
3. The caller can then read or write the entry at any slot as desired (just like with a `vector`)
4. The caller can then efficiently enumerate the non-default entries

(How I've actually implemented this container is irrelevant so I won't go there.)

Now I'm trying to design an iterator for it, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how.

On the one hand, the iterators should be random-access, because the container is essentially a sparse `vector`, and otherwise behaves more or less identically.

On the other hand, the "default" entry for each slot is assumed to be ignorable; that is, it is intended that evaluating something like `for_each(lut.begin(), lut.end(), func)` can and *does* necessarily skip the slots with default values (for substantial speedup).

The problem:

#### How do I properly design an iterator for this class? Does it even make sense to?

Currently, I'm thinking of implementing it such that `iterator::operator++` increments the iterator to point to the next non-default entry, whereas `iterator::operator+(d)` simply adds an offset `d` regardless of whether the entry at that slot is valid or not. So "incrementing" no longer means "adding 1".

Which, on the face of it, sounds ridiculous.
But I can't think of a better way.
Is there one?

Comment: Your ideas for `operator++` and `operator+` conflict. In fact, to be a valid random access iterator, doing `it + 5` must be the same as doing `it++` 5 times. Even though it is sparse, I would still expect the iterator to iterate over every element. The elements are still there, at least logically.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: *"Which, on the face of it, sounds ridiculous."*... yes I know, that's precisely why I asked the question. Did you read that?

Comment: @JosephMansfield: Regarding your edit: The entire *point* of the container is that it be used *only* in those situations in which iteration over the default entries is guaranteed to be a no-op by the user. So if your expectation is that it iterate over default entries too, then you're *not* supposed to be using this container in the first place. My question is, *if* you're using this container and therefore skipping the default entries *is* correct and is also what you expect (e.g. because you require the time complexity reduction), how would you implement iterators that behave reasonably?

Comment: It seems your API should provide two different kind of iterators.

Comment: @jxh: That's actually a great answer, would you mind posting it as one?

Comment: I am concerned with your requirement. `operator++()` and `operator+(1)` should not be different at all.

Comment: What is your container really? In general a *sparse* array/matrix/vector is a container that efficiently holds *all* of the values when there are only a few that are not defaulted. That all of the default values don't take space in the container is nothing but an implementation detail and often times not even visible to the user. On the other hand: *evaluating something like for_each(lut.begin(), lut.end(), func) can and does necessarily skip the slots with default values* seems to indicate that the presence of the values is a *salient* attribute of your container...

Comment: … if you are going to go this way, how should the container work if the user intentionally stores the default value? Is that part of the iteration or is it not? These are important higher level design questions that should be answered before considering the iterators, and will lead to the answer of the iterator question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Good questions, but the answers are pretty clear. It really *is* a sparse container -- you can think of it as simply a sparse vector (in a mathematical sense if that's easier). The presence of a default value is semantically assumed (by both the caller and callee) to be equivalent to its absence -- only the performance is affected if you explicitly insert the default value. However, because the container is sparse (say, the caller knows only log N elements are non-default), the caller *requires* the guarantee that iteration will take O(log N) time, not O(N).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: An easy example: imagine a graph where nodes have been numbered with consecutive integer IDs. I want to associate some property with each node -- say, the number of times that node has been visited. Performance is critical, and the caller wants lookups to be as instantaneous as possible -- hence the need for a LUT. But if the caller suddenly wants to iterate over all the nodes that have been visited at all, that should *not* take O(N) time if only log N nodes have been visited. So I want the iterators to skip over uninitialized elements, because that would be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really describing two different kind of iterators: One that skips over default values when incremented, and one that does not.

So, it seems the API should just provide a way to present either kind to the container user, so that the user gets to choose the behavior they want out of the iterator.